# Opening document located in application directory by another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the following code which tries to open file with default reader:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
// type can be "application/msword" or "application/pdf"
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

File is located on Android device within the application folder:

```
/data/data/air.com.foo.foo/com.foo.foo/Local Store/folder1/file.ppt
```

The problem is that launched activity fails to find the file. I checked for file presence in caller code so it is not the problem.

Furthermore, activity finds the file if I copy it from application folder to a folder shared by applications (on sdcard).

I don't understand why it fails since I have added:

```
intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

The problem is that copying file to a shared folder for me is not a satisfactory solution as I would like it to stay within my initial application folder.

Comment: Intent.addFlag won't help you. This is a permission problem on the file itself. Can we see the code from the launched activity?

Comment: Launched activity is not mine as it can be pdf reader, office reader ...

Comment: Then it's a file permission problem. Make sure the file is readable to the other application (see suggested answer below). If you must, write a test app that tries to read the file do you can see where the problem lies

Answer (score 0):

In the activity that has access to the file, You probably want to do a

```
file.setReadable(true, false);
```

the true is for readability, the false is for "owner only".

Since you can find it, but not read it, it would seem that lacking this permission is the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this one with no success. It only works if file is copied to sddata folder